# Should the model be trained in every Bootstrap iteration?

Tags: logistic, confidence-interval, bootstrap

I am working in a classification scenario and I want to calculate a 95% confidence interval for my test set error rate.

When I am using the Bootstrapping method:

- Shall I train the model once on the training dataset, and resample the testing data set N times to obtain N estimates of the error?
- Or shall I be, training the model on a resampled training dataset for every bootstrap iteration and estimating the error on a resampled testing dataset under that model iteration?

I feel like it's the second but I am having a discussion with a friend and we disagree...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you refer to the bootstrap estimators of an error rate as suggested in

> B. Efron: Estimating the Error Rate of a Prediction Rule: Improvement on
>   Cross-Validation. Journal of the American Statistical Association 78, pp. 316-331 (1983)

The article seems to be inaccessible behind a paywall, but Andrew Webb ("Statistical Pattern Recognition", 2nd ed., 2002) describes the algorithm for the *bootstrap zero estimator* as follows:

```
Input: training set T = {x_1, ..., x_n}  
Output: bootstrap estimator ê_boot of error rate  
For k = 1, ..., K  
    Draw from T randomly n traning samples S_k = { y_1, ..., y_n } with replacemment
    Train Classifier with S_k
    ê_A <- error rate with S_k as test set
    ê_T <- error rate with T as test set
    B_k <- ê_T - ê_A
EndFor
Train Classifier with T
ê_A <- error rate with T as test set
ê_boot <- ê_A + \frac{1}{K}\sum_{k=1}^{K} B_k
Return ê_boot
```

Obviously this estimator requires to train the classifier K+1 times. It is not sufficient to only sample the test data. The same applies to Efron's *.632 bootstrap estimator*, about which is said:

> The .632 estimator performed best in the sampling experiments but has the weakest theoretical justification. (Hand, 1986)

Comment: What will be the typical value of K? Sounds like this will be not practical for models that need a lot of time to train like neural networks or gradient boosting trees if K is 1000 like typical bootstrapping.

Comment: @LouisYang You are right: if training takes days or weeks, this is not feasible. Note, however, that leave-one-out requires even more training operations, because usually the number of training samples is greater than the recommended value for K (for parametric bootstraps it is smaller than for non-parametric bootstraps).